# how to write regex for matching Reference # 11223344 for .net

Tags: regex

sample data

```
Reference # 12345678
```

Regex I have tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pLZSx8/1):

```
(?<=Reference #)[ ]\d{8}\b
```

I am getting space inside the match, how to remove it from the match and put in the look behind instead.

Comment: I understood that the problem is an unknown number of spaces, right? Because `(?<=Reference # )\d{8}\b` is something you should have tried yourself, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCRE (the option you used at the regex testing online Web site), you can use

```
Reference\s+#\s+\K\d{8}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZFhxa/1).

In .NET, you can use

```
(?<=Reference\s+#\s+)\d{8}\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZFhxa/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Reference\s+#\s+)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Reference` + one or more whitespaces, `#` and then one or more whitespaces
- `Reference` - a word
- `\s+#\s+` - a `#` char with one or more whitespaces both on the left and right
- `\K`  - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\d{8}` - eight digits
- `\b` - a word boundary (you might want to replace it with a right-hand digit boundary, `(?!\d)`, if you plan to get a match if the eight digits are bordering on a letter or underscore).

Comment: I would rather use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, because `\d` also matches everything considered a digit in Unicode, like `௫` (Tamil Digit Five)

Comment: @decorator-factory No need to, there is `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option in .NET `Regex`: `var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=Reference\s+#\s+)\d{8}\b", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)?.Value;`. Moreover, `\d` vs. `[0-9]` difference is only important when *validating*, not during *extration*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey, you deleted my question about (?>...) but it's impossible to find the question in Google or even with StackOverflow AI unless you already know what is the name of the thing. Try to search for it (without using its name) and tell me when you found it and what query did you used.

Answer (score 1):

Using a capture group:

```
\bReference # (\d{8})\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bReference #`  Match literally preceded by a word boundary
- `(\d{8})` Capture 8 digits in **group 1** (use `[0-9]` to match digits 0-9 in .NET)
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcQbjn/1).